# How do I make Vim always display several lines after EOF?

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling, cursor

In Vim, I don't like how when you reach end of file it puts the last line at the bottom of the screen.

Is there anyway to make the last line be something like 10 lines above the bottom of the screen and just make blank lines under it?

Comment: When your cursor reach the last line of the file, if you hit `zz` it will redraw the screen and position the current line at the center of the window which should display a few `~` lines after EOF.

Comment: yes, but if you move the cursor again positioning it at the bottom again.

Comment: It sounds like you have the `scrolloff` option set. Try `:set scrolloff=0` and that behavior should change.

Comment: You can read your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406814/in-vim-how-do-you-scroll-a-buffer-so-the-cursor-location-is-centered-in-the-scr There are more answers to this, basically it is not possible, only with workarounds.

Comment: Indeed the behavior has been corrected! thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep X-rows below current cursor position if fewer than Y-rows are left](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/39021/keep-x-rows-below-current-cursor-position-if-fewer-than-y-rows-are-left)

Comment: The vimscript code I provided in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/how-can-i-make-zz-not-center-cursor-when-approaching-end-of-file/42798#42798) could be modified to produce the desired window scrolling.  @OP, if you want, I can take a stab at it and provide an answer here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to scroll down your file, when you are at the end of the file it will add "virtual" line so the last line of the file is not at the bottom of the windows.

Additionally you can use the option `scrolloff` to always let some lines after your cursor, add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
set scrolloff=10
```

For more details see [`:h 'scrolloff'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27scrolloff%27) and [`:h CTRL-E`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#CTRL-E).

Comment: Unfortunately, setting `scrolloff` to 10 will still not show lines AFTER EOF like OP wanted.

Comment: Indeed, that's why I suggested using `CTRL-E` and ̀`scrolloff` was just "additional". Now it is a partial solution, OP is free not to accept it since it doesn't completely answer the question.

Comment: Although it is just a partial solution i think `CTRL-E` is what i was looking for. I'd love if there was a way to display the lines after EOF automatically though.

Comment: @Miguel I'm glad it fits your needs. I think it could be possible to create a mapping which would call `<C-e>` when you scroll down but I'm really not sure it would work correctly... I'll try and see what is possible to do but I'm not sure I'll be able to create something convenient.

Answer (score 5):

In your config you can add `zz` to `j` and `k`. It has the major side effect of centering your cursor. I don't mind and much prefer it to craning my neck. I tried `scrolloff` and `CTRL-E` is just uncomfortable to me.

Type the following in `:` or .vimrc

`nnoremap j jzz`

`nnoremap k kzz`

Sourced: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_your_cursor_centered_vertically_on_the_screen

Comment: When using @carlos-vigil tips, you might want to add `nnoremap G Gzz` to keep consistent behavior when navigating to end of the file with `G`.