# Keeping the window filled with the document

Tags: scrolling

I would like to make Vim behave a little more like the less(1) pager: if I scroll to the bottom of the document (e.g. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>), I want the last line of the file to be displayed at the bottom of the screen, not any higher. Is there a setting that will get me this behavior?

If there isn’t a setting, I imagine I could rig up some kind of mapping where <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> behaves like <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> when the last line is visible after scrolling. But of course a built-in setting would be preferable!

(This is sort of the opposite of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7699/671) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406814/in-vim-how-do-you-scroll-a-buffer-so-the-cursor-location-is-centered-in-the-scr).)

Comment: The vimscript code I provided in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26019/how-can-i-make-zz-not-center-cursor-when-approaching-end-of-file/42798#42798) could be modified to produce the desired window scrolling.  @OP, if you want, I can take a stab at it and provide an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *workaround* to achieve this:

```
:set scrolloff=999
```