# Keep X-rows below current cursor position if fewer than Y-rows are left

Tags: vimscript

I recently started using Vim to write my notes after moving away from VS Codium for this. I'm really enjoying the speed and the ability to navigate keyboard only, but there is one thing that is slightly annoying and I was wondering if there is already a solution.

I understand that `scrolloff` will keep space above and below a cursor but this is when scrolling through a file. It doesn't work when typing. I understand that `zz` will recenter the file on the cursor position and that `Ctrl-e` moves down one line. So when I'm writing and I'm reaching the end of the file, I could `zz` or `Ctrl-e` to adjust the position. However, I was wondering if there was a way to automate this, something like:

```
if (eof - :.) < 5
  zz
```

Or something along those lines?

Comment: It sort of works, but not quite how I was hoping. I think it's the closest I'll get anyway based on what I've been finding. Maybe it's time to get a bit of experience with vimscript to see if I could do something like that. Thank you for the reply though, it's closer than what I've found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use autocommands to invoke `<C-E>` when the cursor gets within `&scrolloff` of the bottom of the window.

Here's an adaptation of [my answer to a similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26055/343) that implements the above:

```
augroup ScrollOffAtEnd
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved * call ScrollOffAtEnd(0)
  autocmd TextChangedI * call ScrollOffAtEnd(1)
augroup END

function ScrollOffAtEnd(insert_mode) abort
  while winheight(0) > &scrolloff && winline() > winheight(0) - &scrolloff
    let at_end = a:insert_mode ? getcursorcharpos()[2] > len(getline('.')) : 0
    execute "normal!\<C-E>"

    " Fix position of cursor when 'wrap' occurs
    if at_end
      let cursor_pos = getcursorcharpos()
      let cursor_pos[2] = cursor_pos[2] + 1
      call setcursorcharpos(cursor_pos[1:])
    endif
  endwhile
endfunction
```

Comment: This is more like what I was trying to describe. Right now this does what I wanted, which is to keep adding space below the line I'm currently typing. So that's great, thank you!

Comment: @pSYoniK Glad I could help.